# Up and down quark content of neutral pion

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, isospin-symmetry, pions

If isospin were a perfect symmetry, then the neutral pion would have equal $u\bar u$ and $d\bar d$ content, but since up quarks are slightly lighter than down quarks, the neutral pion, being the lightest neutral meson, should have a slightly higher proportion of $u\bar u$  than of $d\bar d$.  What does experiment have to say about this?  Is pion-neutron scattering (perhaps using deuterium targets) measurably different from pion-proton scattering?

Comment: Neutral pions have a lifetime around $0.1\,\mathrm{fs}$. You can't make a beam of them, so measurements would have to be *productions* measurements. I find lots of references to production cross-section measurements of various sorts, so there is probably sufficient data to extract an estimate, but I don't know of such a paper off the top of my head and a quick google didn't turn one up.

Comment: Could it connect to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/9803011)?

Comment: Or [this](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/papers/conway_prd_39_92_89.pdf)? Apologies for the indiscriminate scattershot ...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not just "no", but "not even close". Those two papers involve measurement of the quark content of *nucleons* and have nothing to do with mesons. Drell-Yan measurements are useful because you can build the detector to exclude meson junk. In E866 (the subject of the arXiv paper, and a project I was peripherally involved with but not at a level that would lead to authorship of their papers) that was accomplished by stacking up tons of copper, carbon and borated-plastic in the hollow of the motor-coach sized main magnet.

Comment: (We built the absorber wall by passing bars, blocks and sheets of copper, graphite and borated-poly from hand-to-hand while sitting  in a row inside the magnet. Not enormously hard work (except for the thesis student who was stacking the wall), but sweaty because the meson east experimental hall is only moderately well air conditioned.)

Comment: Of course I appreciate that... I just reached for commentary on the fit of Table V of the UC/PU one, not knowing what to ask, specifically.... But the bars story may be worth it...

Comment: Ah yes ... I did not stop to think how hard it is to herd cats, especially invisible ephemeral Cheshire cats.

Comment: This paper deals on the theoretical part, QCD and QED, http://www.phys.uconn.edu/emsplit/emsplit08.pdf  "Isospin symmetry breaking effects in the pion and nucleon masses"