# Structure functions for mesons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, mesons

I was researching about structure functions and understand how it's a probability density function that describes the distribution of quarks inside hadrons. However, since mesons also have quark gluon interactions, I struggle to see why there can't be a structure function for mesons. Yet when I try to search and find it, only structure functions for hadronic currents come up. Therefore I just want to ask:

Can mesons have structure functions and if not, how could it be possible to describe the distribution and behaviour of quarks inside a meson?

Comment: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.32404

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374091/up-and-down-quark-content-of-neutral-pion).

Answer (score 1):

Experimental knowledge of the partonic structure of mesons (the pion and kaon) is very limited due to the lack of a stable pion target! Our current knowledge of the pion structure function in the valence region is obtained primarily from pionic Drell-Yan scattering, and in the pion sea region at low Bjorken-x, from hard diffractive processes measured on e − p collisions at HERA. These data seem to indicate that the pion sea has approximately one-third of the magnitude of the proton sea, while from the parton model one expects the pion sea to be two-thirds of the proton sea. But...
at large Bjorken-x virtually nothing is known about the contribution of sea quarks and gluons.

The Electron-Ion Collider (EIC) with an acceptance optimized for forward physics has the potential for accessing pion and kaon structure functions over a large kinematic region through the Sullivan process, where one measures the contribution to the electron Deep Inelastic Scattering (DIS) of the meson cloud of a proton target:  the nucleon parton distributions contain a component which can be attributed to the meson cloud. [image]

- Sullivan processes. In these examples, a nucleon’s pion cloud is used to provide access to the pion’s (a) elastic form factor and (b) parton distribution functions. $t = (k − k′)^2$ is a Mandelstam variable and the intermediate pion, $π^∗(P = k − k′)$, $P^2 = t$, is off-shell.

Three informative refs are:

1. Aitkenhead, et al. "Determination of the pion and kaon structure functions." [*Physical Review Letters* **45**
   (1980)  157](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.157) .
2. Collins, & Martin, "Hadron reaction mechanisms." [*Reports on Progress in Physics* **45** (1982) 335](https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/45/4/001). Section 6.1.
3. Aguilar et al, "Pion and kaon structure at the electron-ion collider" [*European Physical Journal*  **A55** (2019) 1-15](https://doi.org/10.1140/epja/i2019-12885-0).